# Get database session expire time

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to get value of database session expire time?

I have session that I want to kill, but I don't have enough privileges to do it. 
I can see the session in v$session:

```
SELECT * FROM v$session where osuser = 'osuser' and username='username';
```

As far as I understand session expire time is set in sqlnet.ora. (Obviously I don't have access to check.) Is there any select that I can execute to get the value of session expire time? 
I'm using Oracle Database 10g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed, `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME` is set in the sqlnet.ora configuration file.

> Is there any select that I can execute to get the value of session
>   expire time?

Unfortunately no, there is no data dictionary view available that would allow you to display  content of the sqlnet.ora. So, if you have no access to the file to view its content, and also has not been granted `alter system` privilege, you probably should ask your system administrator or DBA for help.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I tried to get SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME to decide whether to bother DBA with my request or the session will die itself. Looks like I don't have choice.